# Microsoft Excel Copy Cells to Word

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy excel cells into a word document - just the content and not the formatting. For example, I want to copy these cells: A5 (which is a date format) as the first line, cells (E5, K5, L5) in the line after and cells (N5, P5, T5, U5) as the last line in word. I want to do the same for the next row up to the last row where data is available.

For example, in word, I want the content from the excel cells in this format:

```
A5
E5 K5 L5
N5 P5 T5 U5

A6
E6 K6 L6
N6 P6 T6 U6

[...]
```

Update:

I've been able to pull everything from excel to word. However, the font needs to be changed for specific cells. I'm parsing to find the length of the cell and modifying that portion to change to a different text, but it isn't working, and I'm completely lost.

```
Sub Convert_to_Word()

Dim rng As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim Wordrng As Word.Range
Dim lRow As Long

'WordDoc.Content.Style = ("No Spacing")

Set sh = ActiveSheet

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
Set Wordrng = WordDoc.Range(Start:=0)

' Find Last Row of Data
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Needed to establish wordrng in doc
Wordrng.InsertBefore ("")

Base = 0
c = 0

' After each insertion, Wordrng includes the new text
' Copying Content Over
For lRow = 5 To FinalRow

    lenOfE = Len(sh.Range("E" & lRow))
    lenOfDate = Len(sh.Range("A" & lRow))

    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("A" & lRow)) & vbCrLf

    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("E" & lRow)) & " "

    Set WordrngofE = WordDoc.Range(Start:=Base + lenOfDate + 1, End:=Base + lenOfDate + 1 + lenOfE)
    WordrngofE.Font.Name = "Calibri"

    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("K" & lRow)) & " "
    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("L" & lRow)) & vbCrLf

    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("N" & lRow)) & " "
    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("P" & lRow)) & " "
    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("T" & lRow)) & " "
    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("U" & lRow)) & " "
    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("V" & lRow)) & vbCrLf

    c = c + lenOfDate
    Base = WordDoc.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticCharacters) + (14 * (lRow - 4)) + c '+ (lenOfDate * (lRow - 4))

Next lRow

End Sub
```

The "Base + lenOfDate + 1" is to account for an index error. The (14 * (lRow - 4)) doesn't make any logical sense, I added it to compensate the fact that characters after the cell I want to change is being modified instead.

Update 2:

So I decided not to take the approach from Update 1. Instead, I'm trying a different method, however it is throwing back an error: "Object doesn't support this property or method" for "selStart = Selection.Start".

Ref: [Excel VBA: setting font style and size while adding text to MS-Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975012)

```
Sub Convert_to_Word()

Dim rng As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim Wordrng As Word.Range
Dim lRow As Long

Dim selStart As Long

Set sh = ActiveSheet
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

WordApp.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
Set Wordrng = WordDoc.Range(Start:=0)

' Find Last Row of Data
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Establish WordRng in Doc
Wordrng.InsertBefore ("")

    'Wordrng.Font.Name = "Arial"
    'Wordrng.Font.Size = 7
    'Wordrng.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack

    ' After each insertion, Wordrng includes the new text
    ' Copying Content Over
    For lRow = 5 To FinalRow

        lenOfE = Len(sh.Range("E" & lRow))
        lenOfDate = Len(sh.Range("A" & lRow))
        selStart = Selection.Start

        Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("A" & lRow)) & vbCrLf

        'Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("E" & lRow)) & " "

        WordDoc.Range(selStart).InsertAfter (sh.Range("E" & lRow)) & " "
        With WordDoc.Range(selStart, selStart + lenOfE)
            .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
            .Font.Size = 15
        End With

        ' TRIAL
        '--- Remove selection. This will move the cursor at end of selected word
        'Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

        '--- Select the inserted word
        'Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(sh.Range("E" & lRow)), Extend:=wdExtend
        'Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        'Selection.Font.Size = 7

        Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("K" & lRow)) & " "
        Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("L" & lRow)) & " "
        Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("V" & lRow)) & vbCrLf

    Next lRow

WordApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And include the code you are trying to work through...so people can help.

Comment: Not an easy task you've set for yourself as your first VBA program :)  As Rdster says, you need to do some work on it before we can help you, but I will give you some pointers.  First, record some macros and then use the editor to see how they work.  Play around a bit.  Second, you need to set a reference to Word in the Tools>References section of your project, so you can manipulate a word document.  Third, you need to either select the cells you want one at time and paste them into the word document text, or copy them as a range and paste them (maybe as a table?).  Play around a bit more :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found this intriguing, so I went ahead and worked on it.  I don't usually work with VBA in Word, so it's probably pretty primitive, but it's a place for you to start.  Remember, you must add Word to the references in the Excel VB editor.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Make_Word_Doc()
Dim rng As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim Wordrng As Word.Range

Set sh = ActiveSheet

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
Set Wordrng = WordDoc.Range(Start:=0)

Wordrng.InsertBefore ("") 'seems to be needed to establish wordrng in the document.
'after each insertion, Wordrng includes the new text

'work on these commands to place the text where you want it.
Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("A5")) & vbCrLf
Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("E5")) & " "
Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("K5")) & "  "
Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("L5")) & vbCrLf
Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("N5")) & vbTab
Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("P5")) & vbTab
Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("T5")) & vbTab
Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("U5")) & vbCrLf

Stop 'take this out when you're done playing around

WordDoc.Close False ' this will close the file without saveing.  handy for testing
WordApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: it worked! The only dilemma I'm facing is that I have specific cells, E5, N5 and P5 as a different font and I want to copy the same font onto the word document as well. I tried Range.Font.Name and other functions but it isn't working. Any ideas? Also, how would you make the cluster of InsertAfter loop until the final row (i.e., row 1 to 500)?  `FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: `For lRow = 5 To 387

    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("A" & lRow)) & vbCrLf
    
    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("E" & lRow)) & " "
    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("K" & lRow)) & " "
    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("L" & lRow)) & vbCrLf
    
    Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("N" & lRow)) & " "

Next lRow` I got it to parse through all my rows! How do I change font for one specific cell in word? @Hrothgar

Comment: Hmm, I'll have a look at that.  One thing to try, while I'm doing other things, is to record a word macro and see how it does it.  Then you can transfer that code over to your excel sheet and modify it to suit.

Comment: I added an update to my code, check it out @Hrothgar

Comment: yeah, now you're cooking with gas!  Keep on tweaking.  You could grab the font face and size from the spreadsheet cell, and copy them in the word range too. Text colour, bold, etc.  You should be able to duplicate virtually any formatting from one to the other.  One other thing.  Try to be sure to dimension all your variables before you use them.  It prevents errors due to misspellings if nothing else.  Put "Option Explicit" up before the first sub and then compile, and you'll get a warning for every variable that isn't declared.  I should have done that in my example, sorry.  Added.

Comment: Might be a beginner question, but how do you grab the font face and size from the spreadsheet during the WordRng.InsertAfter. Thank you for the advice with "Option Explicit"! I've added Update 2, please have a look. it is throwing back an error: I'm getting this error: "Object doesn't support this property or method" for "selStart = Selection.Start".

Comment: I think it's the selection.start part that is wrong.  Not sure what selection is at this point.  Instead, try selStart = wordrng.start maybe?  Also, for capturing cell formats, you can use properties such as sh.range ("E5").Font.Name, .Font.FontStyle, and .Font.Size to capture the font details from the spreadsheet.  Here's a trick I use a lot:  after you set a variable that you're interested in, put a stop command.  When the code stops there, you can use the watches window to examine that variable, and you will see all of the properties of that object.  Then you'll know the structure of it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The only issue is that sh.range"E5" only changes the cell properties in excel and not the word document (when it's copied over). Any way I can change it after the cell has been copied over? When I copy the excel cell, I want to retain all its properties. `       Wordrng.InsertAfter (sh.Range("E" & lRow).Font.Name = "Calibri") & " "` says "False" when copied over. I changed to Wordrng.Start and it doesn't change the right characters to the proper font. `With WordDoc.Range(lenOfDate, lenOfDate + lenOfE + 1)` This is confusing.. I'd appreciate anymore advice!  @Hrothgar

Comment: oh.  What I meant was, after you copy over the value of E5, you can copy the format by getting the font, etc from the worksheet, and setting the same font in the word document.  so myfont = sh.range ("E5").font.name:  wrdrange(start, stop).font.name = myfont, or something like that.  You'll have to fight with the wrdrange part to get the exact range you want.